# ¿Cómo usar like en una consulta preparada? =

Tags: php, mysql

Aquí estoy consultando el nombre del producto a través de una consulta preparada pero ahora quisiera que la consulta me traiga todos los registros parecidos usando `LIKE` pero no me funciona no se como usarlo aquí en esta consulta:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['nom'])){
        $nom = $_POST["nom"];
        //echo $nom;
        $sentencia = mysqli_prepare($conexion, "SELECT nom FROM producto WHERE nom = ?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sentencia, "s", $nom);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($sentencia);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sentencia, $nombre);

        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($sentencia)){
            echo $nombre."<br>";
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($sentencia);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hola! Por qué dices que no funciona? Podrías añadir a tu pregunta (editandola) lo que intentaste para usar LIKE en la consulta?

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que ponerle los delimitadores a la variable y nada más, algo así:

```
$nom = "%$_POST[nom]%";
$sentencia = mysqli_prepare($conexion,"SELECT nom FROM producto WHERE nom LIKE ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sentencia, "s", $nom);
//Resto del código
```

De ese modo `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` pasará el valor que haya en `$nom` sin ningún problema, notarás, por supuesto, que la consulta ha sido escrita de este modo: `SELECT nom FROM producto WHERE nom LIKE ?`